# Trying to add items to list in Microsoft Graph Callback Succes Method (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have been really struggling with this bit of code. I'm trying to add the items I get returned from the success method into a list. So I can use it in another class (For example an activity). The code actually works when I debug, it shows the items actually adding. But as soon as I run it normally without breakpoints it doesn't work. I think it has something to do with the threading in the background but I'm not that experience with this stuff yet.

My current code:

```
class GraphServiceController {

private final IGraphServiceClient mGraphServiceClient;
private ArrayList<User> users;    

public enum StorageState {
    NOT_AVAILABLE, WRITEABLE, READ_ONLY
}

public GraphServiceController() {
    mGraphServiceClient = GraphServiceClientManager.getInstance().getGraphServiceClient();
    users = new ArrayList<>();
}


public void apiUsers(){

    final IUserCollectionRequest userRequest = mGraphServiceClient.getUsers().buildRequest();
    userRequest.get(new ICallback<IUserCollectionPage>() {
        @Override
        public void success(IUserCollectionPage iUserCollectionPage) {
            addUsers(iUserCollectionPage);                
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(ClientException ex) {

        }
    });

}

public void addUsers(IUserCollectionPage input){
    for(User user : input.getCurrentPage()) {
        users.add(user);
    }

}

public ArrayList<User> getUsers(){
    return users;
}
```

I really hope someone can help me, I've been stuck for hours. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know that you are not receiving any data?

Comment: I am getting data while debugging, but as soon when i run it normally, the getusers method returns 0 users.